# Why my python code keep giving runtime error on codeforces?

Tags: python

this code run with no problems on my laptop but it keep giving runtime error when submitted on codeforces

```
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
k = m*n

if k%2 != 0 :
    print('Akshat')
else:
    print('Malvika')
```

the problem is that the website's compiler try to enter the two variables m , n in the same line while am enter in separate lines ... still can't find the proper way to do that !

Comment: "on codeforces" needs to be clarified. Where is the problem statement?

Comment: sorry for not specifying!!; www.codeforces.com is the website am solving problem on to enhance my programing ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the input comes in one line, you could try to `split` it.

```
m, n = input().split()
m = int(m)
n = int(n)

k = m*n

if k%2 != 0 :
    print('Akshat')
else:
    print('Malvika')
```

Comment: @Shta and what is that error? Please add that to the question.

Comment: @SethMMorton i found the problem but cant solve it .. the problem is that the website's compiler try to enter the two variables m , n in the same line while am enter in separate lines ... still can't find the proper way to do that !

Comment: I see... Can you try the modified answer please?